Swift Package Manager - Warning while trying to access assets
It's the first time I'm creating an SPM Package and I have an error I could not resolve... This is my Package Struct:

And this is my Package.swift:
let package = Package(
name: "MyCustomPackage",
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v15)
],
products: [
    .library(
        name: "MyCustomPackage",
        targets: ["MyCustomPackage"]),
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyCustomPackage",
        dependencies: [],
        path: "Sources/MyCustomPackage",
        resources: [
            .copy("Assets"),
            .process("Fonts")
        ]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyCustomPackage",
        dependencies: ["MyCustomPackage"],
        path: "Tests/MyCustomPackage")
])

If I try to get my custom fonts of the package everything is correct, but when I'm trying to get the assets, my Package give's me a warning:

I have try to add the assets with process instead of copy, to have the Assets under Package directly and more things I have read on the internet, but I can't find any solution, always the same error.
What I'm missing and why I cannot find my assets?
Thank you for your time and your answer :)
P.D.: I'm working on xCode15.2

Not 100% sure but I think your path is wrong. The Target is always in this path so it is looking at sources/MyCustomPackage/Sources/MyCustomPackage.
Try deleting the path property and also try moving all assets in one Folder called Resources. Then use .process("Resources")

Thank you for the advice, finally my problem was that I need to close the package project and open it again to refresh it.
